# How to modify http_host in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

How to modify the return of `request()->getHttpHost()` in Laravel 5.

I used a middelware to modify `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`, but it was not affected.

```
class ModifyHttpHost
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'another.com';
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to do something like that?